# Image Disappears When I Change Height/Width

Tags: java

I have the following Java code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon("/Users/vhaislsalisc/Documents/workspace/Role_Switcher/greenCheck.png", "Success!");
            JLabel checkMark = new JLabel(i1);


            if (requesterRole.isSelected())
            {
                try
                {
                    PreparedStatement ps1, ps2;
                    ps1 = con.prepareStatement("delete from hib.personrole where personid = ?");
                    ps2 = con.prepareStatement("delete from hib.persongroup where personid = ?");

                    ps1.setInt(1, userID);
                    ps2.setInt(1, userID);

                    ps1.execute();
                    ps2.execute();

                    userRoleLbl.setText("The user is a requester");

                    checkMark.setBounds(400, 125, 100, 100);
                    panel.add(checkMark);


                }
```

The image I have is 200x200 pixels. When I change the `checkMark.setBounds()` height or width the image disappears. However, what I have now is only displaying a portion of the image. I am sure that I am doing something wrong, I simply do not know what that could be.

It almost looks like it is behind another element, although none of the elements on my screen stretch over that far. I looked up bringing an element to the front and it was suggested that to do this I would need to override `isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()` to `false` and then I added under the `checkMark.setBounds()`, a `checkMark.isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()` is that how I would handle this, to bring the element to the front?

Comment: Are you using this: checkMark.setBounds(400, 125, 200, 200); ?

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk Yes, and it disappears when I choose height/width of 200. It only appears (partially) with the 100, 100 as I have in my code sample.

Comment: How big is your window?

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk 800 x 600

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code to look like so, and it worked:

```
//Create Success Image
            ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon("/Users/vhaislsalisc/Documents/workspace/Role_Switcher/greenCheck.png");
            i1.paintIcon(changeRoleBtn, getGraphics(), 400,25);
            JLabel checkMark = new JLabel(i1);
            checkMark.isOptimizedDrawingEnabled();

            if (requesterRole.isSelected())
            {
                try
                {
                    PreparedStatement ps1, ps2;
                    ps1 = con.prepareStatement("delete from hib.personrole where personid = ?");
                    ps2 = con.prepareStatement("delete from hib.persongroup where personid = ?");

                    ps1.setInt(1, userID);
                    ps2.setInt(1, userID);

                    ps1.execute();
                    ps2.execute();

                    userRoleLbl.setText("The user is a requester");
                    panel.add(checkMark);

                }
```